# Does change in retention time in server.properties file require restart of zookeeper?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have recently updated the **log.retention.hours** config in **server.properties** file from 168 hours to 730 hours. After this change i have restarted all the brokers in cluster. Does this require a restart of zookeeper nodes as well ? Is there a way to check if the retention time settings is applied ?

Answer (score 0):

Zookeeper does not need restarted to apply that change, only the brokers.

I believe the only way to see the configuration that has not been overridden at a topic level is to inspect the brokers property files.

You can wait a week to see if data is still in the broker (assuming that segments have been closed as well)